# Curl Cmd to Curl php Conversion

Tags: php, curl

```
curl -X POST -d 'something'
```

What curl function of php can be used to set the '-d' of the above curl command line command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check [this](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

Also, take a look at [this](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2011/posting-json-data-with-php-curl)

The function you are looking for, should be:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'something');
```